Using GUIs with WSL2, MobaXterm and Ubuntu
I have a setup for running programs with GUIs in Ubuntu with MobaXterm and Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. In my .bashrc I set the DISPLAY variable with export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0. Now this seems not to work on my work ethernet or Wifi connection - if I run a program like emacs in an Ubuntu terminal, it just hangs, and I need to interrupt it with Ctrl+C, and then I get output "Display ... unavailable" (where ... is the value of DISPLAY).
The question is basically does anyone know what can work now to allow GUIs in Ubuntu using MobaXterm with WSL2?
It does work when I'm connected to my home Wifi, but not when using my phone as a hotspot. I can also launch GUIs from MobaXterm's own terminal instances (that are not running Ubuntu, I presume). I created this setup in mid-2020 and it worked on my work network at least up to December 19 2023 - I've not had to use this set up very often for a while, and didn't precisely record when I did use it successfully since. I mention that as this post says the Windows 23H2 update broke X11 forwarding for them, so the issue may be related to updates, but their setup is different to mine and the fixes mentioned there (using ip route or not setting DISPLAY) don't work for me.
I've tried every other potential solution I could find online to no avail so far (generally they are either old or found to work by people not using MobaXterm) - using $(hostname).local:0, output of route.exe or basing DISPLAY on my IP address given by hostname -I, ifconfig, ip or netshe.exe.
If I set DISPLAY to something clearly invalid, emacs does not hang but goes straight to its "-nw" mode i.e. just being a text editor in the terminal. So it seems to recognise that there is something non-trivial about the addresses returned by most of the methods above, but isn't able to use them correctly.
I've wondered if it could be a Windows Defender Firewall setting, given the difference on my home vs work networks and other posts mentioning this as a potential issue, but I don't see anything that's obviously a problem. But I'm not very familiar with firewall settings, so may just not be looking for the right thing. My work networks and phone hotspot all show up as "Private" networks in the Networks and Internet settings, with no option to change that, and I've not looked yet at whether there is something clearly different about my home Wifi network.
Version info:

Windows 23H2 22631.4317
WSL2 10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800) (output of (get-item C:\windows\system32\wsl.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion)
MobaXterm v.20.1 build 4290
Ubuntu 20.04

Yes WSL, MobaXterm and Ubuntu are quite old I think, as I've been going with "if it ain't broke, don't upgrade it". Perhaps I should upgrade one or more of these components? But I'd rather not risk breaking other aspects of my setup or having to rebuild it, if there's a simpler way to make this work, or there's a minimal amount of upgrading that's necessary.

[Edit] your question to indicate which version of the WSL kernel you have installed.  You also might indicate what version of WSLg you have installed

OK, with a bit more investigating it does seem that changing the Windows Defender Firewall setting is the right fix - adding an inbound rule to allow connections to port 6000 from the range of addresses assigned to DISPLAY seems to allow GUIs to work (for me, the part of the address before the first . (call it X) seems to stay the same, so I set the range to X.0.0.0 to X.255.255.255).
